# Determine the distance between a WiFi access point and a device

Tags: android

I need to know the distance between my phone and WiFi access points.  These points are set up in adjacent rooms.  I researched about Geo Location, but that's been deprecated now ... Basic set-up of my project consists of 3 WiFi access points.  My code is getting the strongest signal and getting connected to that access point.

Now I need to get the distance between that access point and my phone. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: maybe duplicated question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437694/how-to-get-the-connection-strength-of-wifi-access-points

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on my knowledge and following answers, it is not possible to find out distance between your device and WiFi access point. Because basically they don't store GPS location inside.

- [how to get wifi hotspot's location?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086009/how-to-get-wifi-hotspots-location)
- [Location and distance calculation using Wifi in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8921157/location-and-distance-calculation-using-wifi-in-android)

Comment: Thanks 2 all...so is there no way 2 at all to get the distance between them??.....because i am new to android development...

Comment: @AndresL...the link which u have provided answers to get the signal strength and not the distance.....i am getting the signal strength,but i need the distance between my access point and the device.