# Calculating distance between 2 devices using hotspot

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi, signal-strength

I'm trying to calculate the distance between 2 devices using various methods with the given limitations:

- Speed is a huge factor, therefore, authentication / handshake process is a bad idea
- Must be valid for at least 20 meters

I've so far came with the following solutions:

- **Bluetooth** - From my understanding, is going to consume most of the battery, distance is limited and authentication is mandatory(pin code)
- **Audio frequencies** - I know there is a solution by google, but couldn't find anything valuable
- **Wifi** - For this solution, one of the devices must be configured as a hotspot, is it possible to run a lite-weight hotspot service on both sides which would  skip the authentication process, wouldn't offer any internet connection but simply broadcast its existence and signal strength

Comment: Check out [Calculate distance from wifi router using signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217674/how-to-calculate-distance-from-wifi-router-using-signal-strength)    or    [Get distance between wifi access point and mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28231999/how-to-get-distance-between-wifi-access-point-and-mobile-device)