# How to Display Available Wifi hot-spots on google map in android?

Tags: android

In my Android project I access the available WiFi networks.

I want to pin these access point on Google map.
I already integrated Google map in my project, and also displayed the currently connected WiFi location.

I want to display all the available WiFi Hotspots on Google map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that, you need to have latitude and longitude of all wifi hotspots that you want to show on google map.

If you have them, you can display it on the map using markers for e.g

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(10, 10))
        .title("Wifi Location"));
}
```

for additional customization, please read:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: It sounds like he's already got that working, as he's already showing a marker for the current WiFi location.

Comment: The question is not very clear. He might have enabled his current location which shows default marker(blue cirlcle).

Comment: thanks for your response dear .. but  i am already doing it. . . what if i dont know the lat lng and want to show the location of that router/wifi

Comment: You need to get the max signal range of the device and compare the distance to your current location. Then you need a function to solve the lat lng of the available connections based on that distance/radius

Comment: In that case, I am sorry to inform you that it is not possible. Please see this link for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4086009/how-to-get-wifi-hotspots-location